# Read XML property in PHP

Tags: php, xml, properties

I have a problem with PHP and XML. I have an XML datafeed which I want to import to the database. Most of the values are working fine but the properties don't work.

I tried to select the 'brand' property with `$brand = $allData[$key]->property->brand->value;` but it does not work.

This is the PHP which reads the data.xml. After the code comes the XML.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("data.xml");
foreach($xml->children() as $child)
{ 
$allData[] = $child;
}


foreach($allData as $key=>$value)
{
$naam = $allData[$key]->name;
$image = $allData[$key]->images->image;

}
```

--- part of the XML code ----

```
<images>
<image>afbeelding.jpg</image>
</images>
<description>beschrijving</description>
<categories>
<category path="categorie"> Categorie </category>
</categories>

<properties>
<property name="brand">
<value>Merk</value>
</property>
```

I can get the description and image tag quite easy. But the brand does not work.

`$brand = $allData[$key]->property->brand->value;`

Is there anybody who can help me?

Comment: Rather than forcing your XML to act like arrays, read up on the http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php SimpleXMLElement interface. You can use the attributes property to get what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you iterate over something by forcing it into arrays. The short (but bad) answer to your question is:
$brandProperty = (string) $allData[$key]->property->attributes()->name;

Much better: follow Jerry's advice and RTM - read the fine manual. The manual and user contributed notes have all the info you need and more.
SimpleXML implements iteration itself, it's easier to use something like `foreach ($xml->children() as $node)` to run through your document.

Hope that helps.